# How to can I get array elements by Id to do Comparisons?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

My **find matches** function does not seem to be working.

I want to get an array (`[]`) element by id and do comparisons with it.

The function is supposed to go into the array and generate a random person, then display the match in the text area "showmatches".

I am not sure if the random person is being generated nor if the criteria are being matched in the comparison.

```html
<html>
    <head> 
        <script>

var records = [];

function calculateAge() 
{ 
    var dob = document.getElementById('dob').value; 
    var dobInput = new Date(dob);
    
    var now     = new Date(); 
    var year    = now.getFullYear(); 
    var month   = now.getMonth(); 
    var day     = now.getDate(); 
    
    var birthyear   = dobInput.getFullYear(); 
    var birthmonth  = dobInput.getMonth(); 
    var birthday    = dobInput.getDate(); 
    
    var bYear   = year - birthyear; 
    var bMonth  = month - birthmonth; 
    var bDay    = day - birthday; 
    
    if (bYear < 18 || bYear > 75)
    {  
        alert("Age cannot be less than 18 or greater than 75"); 
        return false; 
    }else{
        document.getElementById("age").value = bYear + "years old";
    }
    //document.getElementById("age").value = bYear + "years old";
} 
        
function showAll() 
{ 
    show = document.getElementById("showallpersons").innerHTML=records;
    show.value = records.join("\n");
    
} 
(window.onload = () => {
    var findmatches=document.getElementById('findmatches');
    if(findmatches){
        findmatches.addEventListener('click', findMatches, false);
    }
    function findMatches(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        for(var counter=0; counter<records.length; counter++)
        {
            var currposn = records[counter].value;
            var show = document.getElementById("showallmatches").innerHTML= currposn.fname + currposn.lname;
            show.value = currposn.join("\n");
            
            do
            {
                //From here 
                var randpson = Math.random() * records.length;
                randpson = Math.floor(randpson); //To here works, I know that for sure
                
                
                //I'm not sure if the conditions for the if statements are correct
                if(((randpson.age - currposn.age) <= 10) || ((randpson.age - currposn.age) >= 20))
                {
                    if(((randpson.height - currposn.height) <= 10) || ((randpson.height - currposn.height) >= 20))
                    {
                        var display = document.getElementById("showmatches").innerHTML= "Matched to: " +randpson.fname + randpson.lname;
                        //display.value = "Matched to: " + randpson.fname + randpson.lname;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } while(counter < 10){
                
                //var newDisplay = document.getElementById("showallmatches").innerHTML= null;
            }   
            //console.log(findMatches());
        }
        
    }
})()
(window.onload = () => {
    var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    if(submit){
        submit.addEventListener('click', addnew, false);
    }
    function addnew(event)
    {
        //Prevents default submit event
        event.preventDefault();
        //Accept values entered in form
        var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
        var mname = document.getElementById('mname').value;
        var lname= document.getElementById('lname').value;
        var dob= document.getElementById('dob').value;
        var gender = document.forms['Information']['gender'].value;
        var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
        parseInt(age);
        var bodyType = document.getElementById('Body Type').value;
        var occu= document.getElementById('occu').value;
        var height= document.getElementById('height').value;
        
        if (fname==null || fname=="")
        {  
            alert("A first name is required");  
            return false;
        }
        if(mname==null || mname=="")
        {  
            alert("A middle initial is required");  
            return false;
        }
        if (lname==null || lname=="")
        {  
            alert("A last name is required");  
            return false;
        }
        if(dob==null || dob=="")
        {
            alert("A DOB is required");
            return false;
        }
        if (gender == "") 
        {
            alert("Please select a gender");
            return false;
        } 
        
        if(height <= 170 || height >= 200)
        {
            alert("A height between 170, not less and 200, not more is required");
            return false;
        }
        if(bodyType==null || bodyType==""){
            alert("Please choose a body type");
            return false;
        }
        if(occu==null || occu=="")
        {
            alert("Please enter an occupation");
            return false;
        }
        //Append To array
        
        records.push(fname);
        records.push(mname);
        records.push(lname);
        records.push(gender);
        records.push(age);
        records.push(bodyType);
        records.push(occu);
        records.push(height);
        
        for(i=0;i<records.length;i++)
        {
            console.log(records[i]);
        }
        document.getElementById("Information").reset();
    }
})()
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header class="page-header">
                <nav>
                    <button class="cta-contact">Contact Us</button>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class="space">
            <h1>
                <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right">What are you waiting for? Find your "one" now.</marquee>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <form name="Information" id="Information">
                <fieldset> 
                    <legend>Personal Information</legend>
                First Name: 
                <input id="fname" type="text"  size=40 placeholder='First Name' minlength=4 maxlength=40 required />
                <br/><br/>
                Middle Initial: 
                <input id="mname" type="text"  size=3 placeholder='M Intial' maxlength=1 required />
                <br/><br/>
                Last Name:
                <input id="lname" type="text"  size='40' placeholder='Last Name' minlength='4' maxlength='40' required />
                <br/><br/>
                Date of Birth 
                <input id="dob" type="date" onchange="calculateAge()"/>
                <br/><br/>
                Gender: 
                <input id="male" type="radio" value='M' name="gender" required/> Male
                <input id="female" type="radio" value='F' name="gender" required/> Female
                <br/><br/>
                Age: <input type="text" id="age" disabled />
                <br/>
                Body Type:
                <select id="Body Type">
                    <optgroup label="Female" id="FemaleOpt">
                        <option value="Apple"> Apple </option>
                        <option value="Pear"> Pear </option>
                        <option value="Pencil"> Pencil </option>
                        <option value="Hourglass"> Hourglass </option>
                        <option value="Round"> Round </option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="Male" id="MaleOpt">
                        <option value="Oval"> Oval </option>
                        <option value="Triangle"> Triangle </option>
                        <option value="Rectangle"> Rectangle </option>
                        <option value="Rhomboid">Rhomboid </option>
                        <option value="Inverted">Inverted Triangle</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
                <br/><br/>
                Occupation:  
                <input id="occu" type="text" size=30 maxlength=30 required />
                <br/><br/>
                Height(in cm):  
                <input id="height" type="number" size="3" min="171" max="199" value="" required /><br>
                <br/><br/>
                <textarea id="showallpersons" name="Show All Persons" onclick="showAll()" disabled></textarea>
                <textarea id="showmatches" name="Show All Matches" onclick="findMatches()" disabled></textarea>
                <br/><br/>
                <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
                <button id="findmatches" type="button">Find Matches</button>
            </fieldset>     
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do these steps.  First you have two window.onload = () (As you are not using addEventListener only one event will be attached).

### Steps:

1. Keep everything intact, just remove the window.onload from both places.  Keep all code inside load intact.
2. Move the entire code block just to the bottom of the html above closing  tag. (Doing so, will make window.onload redundant.)

Put console.log() in the click handler and see if it's working (it will)

Let us know.

NOTE:  On other hand there are better way to code this, for e.g wait for DOMContentLoaded for attaching event etc., but it's too big to discuss here.  First make this work, then we can recommend better approaches.

Comment: I am getting this error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fname' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.findMatches (Index.html:295)"

Comment: Please put your minimum reproducible code in jsbin.com or codepen.com or jsfiddle so that the exact issue can be identified.